# VB Express 2008 - Populating a TextBox from a selected ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

This might sound a really stupid question, but I'm not sure on the answer to this. I have the following code in my "OnLoad" of my VB Project, which works fine:

```
 Dim ServName = (From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\Testing\Servers.csv") _
Where line.Length > 0 _ Let Items = line.Split(","c) _ Select New With _ {.ServerRef = Items(0), _ .ServerName = Items(1), _ .ServerIP = Items(2) _ } _ ).ToList

    For Each Server In ServName
        Console.WriteLine("[{0} [{1}] [{2}]", _
                          Server.ServerRef, _
                          Server.ServerName, _
                          Server.ServerIP _
              )
    Next

    Dim h As String
    h = 0
    For Each Server In ServName
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Server(h).ServerRef)
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(Server(h).ServerName)
        ComboBox3.Items.Add(Server(h).ServerIP)

        h = h + 1
    Next
```

But what I now want to do in the ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged section is to pick up the selection you've made from the ComboBox1 and to then pick up the corresponding information in ComboBox3.

For example (in CSV file):

Server1,Cluster1,192.168.0.1

Server2,Cluster2,172.16.16.1

Etc

What I want to do is when you select Server1 that the IP in the 3rd column gets populated into a text box (TextBox1).
As it stands, ComboBox2 & ComboBox3 are just to display that the information is being read in correctly. These won't actually be used.

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood what you want/your exact configuration properly: all the information is being stored in parallel in 3 comboboxes. When a given item in combobox1 is selected you want to write the corresponding item (same index) from combobox3 into a textbox. Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi varobarbas, that's exactly what I want, as I want to be able to use this value (an IP address) in my subroutines. And may want to use the other values as well, but once I've got one up and running then I can get the others working

Comment: (my nick is varocarbas :)) just to make the point clear: my code works perfectly with "conventional" VS (any version: 2008, 2010, etc.) and represents the best solution for your problem, that is, selecting the combobox3 index as a function of the combobox1. The Express version has restricted functionalities with respect to conventional VS; I don't have it installed on my computer and thus I cannot check the exact limitations in this case. The error you report cannot occur in conventional VS because 0 is the first index for any list (including a combobox); that's why I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you are extracting information from the `ServName` list and then discarding the list. The result of that is that there is no way to tell which value in one box belongs to which value in any of the other boxes.

What I want you to do instead is something along these lines:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = ServName
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "ServerRef"

ComboBox2.DataSource = ServName
ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "ServerName"

ComboBox3.DataSource = ServName
ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "ServerIP"
```

Now you can use reference equality to manipulate box2 and box3 depending on what item is selected in box1.

**EDIT**

What's more is you don't even need the other boxes if you follow my approach. You have all the information you need in just 1 box:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim box As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim server As Object = box.SelectedItem

    Dim serverRef As String = server.ServerRef
    Dim serverName As String = server.ServerName
    Dim serverIP As String = server.ServerIP
End Sub
```

Comment: The first part of the script worked brilliantly and they all dynamically update which is exactly what I wanted, but I'm struggling to extract the value into a work field / text box from ComboBox3. I'm still stuggling to extract the value from ComboBox3 (or the associated data) into a text field I can work with.

Comment: Have you tried my code for `SelectedIndexChanged`? Unless I made a mistake, it should give you the information you're looking for without even touching `ComboBox3`. This works because all three boxes now use the exact same list of objects. They just display it differently.

Comment: I do recommend making an actual `ServerInfo` class to hold the string values from the CSV file. Duck-typing in VB.NET makes baby jesus cry.